# The emacsclient documentation has an example with %d and %s arguments - what are they

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

[In the emacsclient documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html#emacsclient-Options), an example EDITOR setting is:

```
EDITOR="emacsclient --alternate-editor emacs +%d %s"
```

How can the %d and %s be used?  I understand that + starts at the specified line and the %s is the file name to edit, but what program replaces %d and %s the values?

For example, if subversion tried to kick of `$EDITOR`, emacs will edit 3 files: `+%d`, `%s`, and the target file.  Is there any program that replaces these %d and %s with the next two arguments?  Is the emacs documentation just incorrect?  Why wouldn't you just set `EDITOR` to `` `emacsclient --alternate-editor emacs ``?

Comment: More appropriate for superuser.com?

Comment: I have `--alternate-editor=""`. those quotes are not needed though. This runs emacs in server mode if the client can't connect.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax mimics the one used by the printf function in C and languages inspired by it: `%d` is intended to be replaced by an integer in decimal notation, and `%s` is intended to be replaced by a string. However, I don't know of any program that will perform such a replacement on the value of `$EDITOR`. This may well qualify as a bug in the Emacs manual.

There are programs that interpret `$EDITOR` as the path to an executable file (a few don't even look up in `$PATH`), and others that interpret it as a shell snippet that starts the editor (allowing passing extra arguments to the executable the way you did). So it's safest to set `EDITOR` to just the full path to an executable, not containing special characters. Use a relay script if you want to pass options, e.g. `EDITOR=~/bin/EDITOR` where the contents of `~/bin/EDITOR` are something like

```
#!/bin/sh
exec emacsclient --alternate-editor emacs
```